# Removing a list of objects of another list from Different Collections

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to work harder with those constructions but definitelly I dont see them deductive. I already made a code like above when I got 2 lists of the same kind ( List ) for example:

```
listA.RemoveAll(x => !listB.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID));
```

Now, supouss that I have the same lists but they are from different collections ( got different attributes into each member of the list) and I would like to delete all the members from list A that doesn't have the same ID from the elements into list B.

Both collections got an int ID attribute to be compared.

Comment: Haven't you already answered your question?

Comment: and why wouldn't your code example work for that case?

Comment: @Hasan Khan, no when listA and listB are different object type the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of deleting from list you can select valid items as bellow:

```
listA = listA.Where(x=>listB.Any(y=>y.ID == x.ID)).ToList();
```